# The typeform is not submitting while entering valid inputs?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('form').attr('action','');
  });
  </script>
```

The  form is submitted through javascript passing the action and url of the page where theform is accessed through.

Comment: are you calling submit() anywhere ? your question is not clear.

Comment: What is your question? And Is it possible to provide some additional information on your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Submit form in jquery you use:

```
$( "#Idbutton" ).click(function() {
  $( "form" ).submit();
});
```